# SystemEvents.TimeChanged fires twice

Tags: c#

I'm using the event SystemEvents.TimeChanged in my Windows Application and it fires twice.
The code that I use:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace DateTimeTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Time changed: {0}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the time in Windows and the event occurs twice. Why?

Comment: Are you sure you only changed the time once? e.g. hour then minute. It's a static event that uses the message pump, so if it chucks a message in on any chnage of anypart of datetime while editing, you could get a passel of them. In fact seeing as there's no enter a value then hit the ok button that's likely is it not?

Comment: I tried to change the time using the DOS command 'Time' and the SystemEvents_TimeChanged event fired two times.

Answer (score 4):

This is MS bug which won't be fixed

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776003/systemevent-timechanged-is-fired-twice

Answer (score 3):

The offending double-firing of `SystemEvents.TimeChanged` does indeed happen when manually setting the clock. It also happens when you switch your Date & Time settings from manual -> automatic (assuming the clock was adjusted as a result):

[image]

So yes, it appears to be a Windows issue. 
There is an easy way around it: use Reactive Extensions to wrap the `SystemEvents.TimeChanged` event and ignore the extraneous event occurrences.

1) Install `System.Reactive` from Nuget
2) use code similar to the following:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IDisposable subscriptionToken = 
                Observable.FromEventPattern(e => SystemEvents.TimeChanged += e, e => SystemEvents.TimeChanged -= e)
                .Select(x => new Unit())
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
                .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("The system clock just changed"));

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            subscriptionToken.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work even if more than two events are fired within a 250 ms timeframe; only the last one will be acted upon

Answer (score 1):

Just unlink this event the 1st time it's fired and problem is solved:

```
static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SystemEvents.TimeChanged -= new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);

    Console.WriteLine("Time changed: {0}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to keep handling legitimate time change events.

Comment: @CCCP I just tested and it worked on a Windows Form in C#. Is it safe to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It just fires the event whenever it receives the [WM_TIMECHANGE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  So you'll need to look for a reason why another program changed the time twice or, maybe over-zealously, changed the system time *and* broadcasted this message.  Hard to speculate since you didn't describe what you did to change the time.

Of course this should **never** be a real problem.

Comment: On Windows 10, right-click clock in taskbar and select "Adjust date/time". Just change minute part of the time and click the "Change" button. The event is fired twice

Comment: More strange things are happening:
When date is changed from 14 (for example) to 13, event fires once. When date is changed back to 14, no event is fired